# WPF RichTextBox Spell Check Ignore certain words

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, spell-checking

Is it possible to ignore alphanumeric words or Ignore case by default? The company I am designing this for wants spellcheck however uses a TON of alphanumeric words which is important to their daily work. However it comes up as being misspelled when it really isn't. Adding these words to the custom dictionary would be pointless as they are not really used over and over

Does anyone know how I can get the spellchecker to ignore this by default?

Comment: _...to ignore this by default?_ To ignore what by default ? Business keywords getting tagged as false positives ? Without adding them to a dictionary ? Sorry but I don't get it..

Comment: Yes business words as false positives without adding to a dictionary. In MS Word you can choose to ignore words with digits and words in UPPERCASE. How can this be done with the WPF spellchecker?